# Sequencing css transitions

Tags: css-transitions

I try to manage how to have a sequence of 2 change of position/size of an element with different transition parameters.

My example is to zoom out a blue box when I click on a red box, the zooming starting from the click position, up to cover all the red box.
Below is the code I tried. But so far, the 2 parts of the transition defined in test.js are done with the same transition parameter.
Any hint ?

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>


  <script src="test.js"></script>
<div id=boxofboxes>
  <div id=redbox onclick=clicked(event)>
  </div>
  <div id=bluebox>
  </div>
  </div>
  

#redbox{
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

#bluebox{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#boxofboxes{
    position: relative;
}

function clicked(event){
    console.log(event);
    let b=document.getElementById("bluebox");
    b.style.display="block";
    b.style.transition="0s";
    b.style.left=event.clientX;
    b.style.top=event.clientY;
    b.style.width="10px";
    b.style.height="10px";

    b.style.visibility="visible";
    
    b.style.transition="1s";
    let r=document.getElementById("redbox");
    b.style.top=0;
    b.style.left=0;
    b.style.width=r.clientWidth;
    b.style.height=r.clientHeight;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the (or at least one) answer to my problem :

Adding :

```
b.focus();
```

after :

```
b.style.visibility="visible";
```

solves the problem: the first part of the sequence is done with transition=0s and the second part with transition=1s